# C hex to dec conversion, I don't understand what's wrong with my code

Tags: c

My code should find hex numbers in a user input (followed or not by 0x), copy them in an array as a string and, every time it finds a non 1-9 a-f A-F character or EOF, it should execute the `htoi` function converting the characters in the string into a decimal number, proceeding from right to left and using a multiplier to account for the position. It doesn't do what it's supposed to do. It generates numbers that have nothing to do with the decimal equivalent of my hex numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <math.h>

int htoi(char num[]);

int main()
{
    int c,i = 0;
    char num[1000];
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if ((c > '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f'))
        {
            num[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        else if (c == '0')
        {
            if ((c = getchar) == 'x' || c == 'X')
            {
                num[i] = '\0';
                printf("%d", htoi(num));
                i=0;
            }
            else
            { 
                 num[i] = c;
                 i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            num[i] = '\0';
            if (num[0] != '\0')
            {
                printf("%d", htoi(num));
            }
            i=0;
        }


    }
num[i] = '\0';
if (num[0] != '\0')
    {
          printf("%d", htoi(num));
    }
i=0;
return 0;
}

int htoi(char num[])
{
    int c,i, dig;
    int  dec;
    int multiplier = 1;

    for (i = strlen(num)-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        c = num[i];
        if (c > '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            dig = c - '0';
        }
        else if (c > 'a' && c <= 'f')
        {
            dig = c - 'a' + 10;
        }
        else if (c > 'A' && c <= 'F')
        {
            dig = c - 'A' + 10;
        }
        dec = dec + dig * multiplier;
        multiplier * 16;
        return dec;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you just `sscanf(s,"%x",&number);` ?

Comment: What do you observe ? what did you expect ? Also, use a debugger to find where your program goes wrong

Comment: `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')` - Hm? It proves that you haven't even read your own code. Of course you don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: `if ((c = getchar) == 'x' ....` => `if ((c = getchar()) == 'x' ....`

Comment: `multiplier * 16` should be `multiplier *= 16`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: Note that `0x` normally precedes the hex value, rather than follows it.  Your code won't handle it because the preceding (slightly dubious) `if` will note that you have a `0` and the code to detect `0x` therefore will not be executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

1. `multiplier * 16;` just throws away the result. You'd want `multiplier *= 16`
2. `return dec` returns *immediately* with the current value of `dec`. You should have that *after* the loop.
3. The variable `dec` is *uninitialized*, which means it will have an indeterminate value. Using it without initialization, like you do, will lead to *undefined behavior*.

There are other problems as well, some of which would have been caught by the compiler leading to errors or warnings. The three above was just what I found after a quick glance.

Comment: Some other problems:

1. `if ((c = getchar) == 'x' || c == 'X')` => should be getchar()
2. `if (c > 'a' && c <= 'f')` => should enclose the lower bound (`c >= a`)